# Generate a Key, Value JSON object from a Ruby Object Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby

I have a Ruby array of `students`. `Student` class has attributes `id`, `name` and `age`.

```
students = [ 
             {id:"id1",name:"name1",age:"age1"}, 
             {id:"id2",name:"name2",age:"age2"},
             {id:"id3",name:"name3",age:"age3"}
           ]
```

I want to create a JSON key value object from this array as follows.

```
json_object = {id1:name1, id2:name2, id3:name3}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
input = [ {id:"id1",name:"name1",age:"age1"},
          {id:"id2",name:"name2",age:"age2"},
          {id:"id3",name:"name3",age:"age3"}]

require 'json'
JSON.dump(input.map { |hash| [hash[:id], hash[:name]] }.to_h)
#⇒ '{"id1":"name1","id2":"name2","id3":"name3"}'
```

Comment: Wow. I had no idea that you could use `.to_h` like that on an array of arrays. Super nice! Would you please comment on `JSON.dump` vs. `.to_json`?

Comment: @jvillian sure. I don’t trust monkeypatches. `to_json` might be explicitly blocked/overwritten/whatever.

Comment: @mudasobwa Is this monkeypatch in Ruby context? Or does this apply to Rails (Hash#to_json) as well?

Comment: @jemonsanto of course there is [`to_json` in the ruby core](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Generating+JSON). The thing is _Rails_ or whoever do extensively overwrite/monkeypatch the default Ruby implementation, and what I need is an old good one from ruby core.

Comment: @mudasobwa Neato! Thanks for the explanation, didn't see the alternative way (doh). Just skimmed on it.

Answer (score 2):

Your data is all identical, but if you wanted to generate a hash that took the value of `students[n][:id]` as keys and `students[n][:name]` as values you could do this:

```
student_ids_to_names = students.each_with_object({}) do |student, memo|
  memo[student[:id]] = student[:name]
end
```

For your data, you'd end up with only one entry as the students are identical: `{ "id1" => "name1" }`. If the data were different each key would be unique on `:id`.

Once you have a hash, you can call `json_object = students_ids_to_names.to_json` to get a JSON string.

Comment: Prefer `each_with_object` over `inject` for mutable accumulators.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a go:

```
students = [ 
             {id:"id1",name:"name1",age:"age1"}, 
             {id:"id2",name:"name2",age:"age2"},
             {id:"id3",name:"name3",age:"age3"}
           ]

json_object = students.each_with_object({}) do |hsh, returning|
  returning[hsh[:id]] = hsh[:name]
end.to_json
```

In console:

```
puts json_object
 => {"id1":"name1","id2":"name2","id3":"name3"}
```